# How to have comments in squid adslist file readen by url_regex?

Tags: squid

To block ads I wrote the following in the beginning of `squid.conf`:

```
acl adslist url_regex -i "/etc/squid/adslist.txt"
http_access deny adslist
```

The file contains a plain list of domain names.

Is it possible to have some line temporarily ignored in this file, like being commented?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can add `#` at the beginning of the line to ignore particular domain being blocked. In your case file to edit would be `/etc/squid/adslist.txt`. For example,

```
www.xyz.com
#www.example.com
www.abc.com
```